# Do I need to get a visa before flying for one month holiday to Peru and Bolivia?

Tags: visas, peru, bolivia, eu-citizens, dutch-citizens

Do I need to get a visa before flying to Peru and Bolivia for one month holiday?

Or can I just get it once I've landed there ?

I'm from Europe (The Netherlands).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No for both countries:

Peru:

> With a few exceptions (notably some Asian, African and communist
>   countries), visas are not required for travelers entering Peru.
>   Tourists are permitted a 30- to 90-day stay, which is stamped into
>   their passports and onto a tourist card, called a Tarjeta Andina de
>   Migración (Andean Immigration Card), that you must return upon leaving
>   the country. The actual length of stay is determined by the
>   immigration officer at the point of entry.

Read more: [lonelyplanet.com](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/peru/practical-information/visas#ixzz2EvX3Tjse)

Bolivia:

> Citizens of most South American and Western European countries can get
>   a tourist card on entry for stays up to 90 days, depending on the
>   nationality.

Read more: [lonelyplanet.com](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/bolivia/practical-information/visas#ixzz2EvXg9RJI)

I had no problem getting 90 days each on the borders.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask: what about Chile ?

Comment: No visa required for Chile for EU Citiziens either, as a matter of fact as a Dutch Citizien you don't need any visa in South America, while other Europeans need just one for Surinam